# NERDTree-ack Error

Tags: vim, nerdtree, ack

I'm unable to get the NERDTree-ack plugin working; when I attempt to search from NERDTree I am met with the following error:

```
Enter the pattern: ack.txtError detected while processing function nerdtree#ui_glue#invokeKeyMap..72..71..<SNR>36_showMenu..46..63..NERDTreeAck:
line   10:
E477: No ! allowed: Ack! ack.txt /home/autodidacticon/.vim/bundle/ack.vim/doc
```

Here is the relevant portion of my .vimrc

```
" let Vundle manage Vundle
 88 " " required!
 89 Bundle 'gmarik/vundle'
 90
 91 " Bundles here
 92 Bundle 'ervandew/supertab'
 93 Bundle 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
 94 Bundle 'ack.vim'
 95 "yunowerk
 96 Bundle 'nerdtree-ack'
 97 Bundle 'Syntastic'
 98 Bundle 'Tagbar'
 99 Bundle 'scrooloose/nerdcommenter'
100 Bundle 'elzr/vim-json'
101 Bundle 'vim-ruby/vim-ruby'
102 Bundle 'moll/vim-node'
103 Bundle 'kchmck/vim-coffee-script'
104 filetype plugin indent on     " required!
105 syntax enable
106
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nerdtree-ack` depends on a later version of `ack.vim` than the one available on `vim.org` (this is mentioned e.g. in [the install details here](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3878)). Rather than specifying

```
Bundle 'ack.vim'
```

You should specify

```
Bundle 'mileszs/ack.vim'
```